# How do I paste reprex to Stack Overflow without manually needing to line space each line of code 4 spaces?

Tags: reprex

I'm newer to posting my questions using `reprex`.  I've watched videos and read articles and have the workflow down to come up with the reprex.  How do I paste the content to Stack Overflow without manually having to space each line by 4 spaces in order to recognize it as code?

Comment: The editor window for questions and answers has a tool in its toolbar to help.  Paste in your code, select it, and click the button with the pair of curly braces (`{}`).  At least one of the selected lines should start out completely unindented.

Comment: Questions about Stack Overflow itself beong on [meta]. This site is for programming related questions.